# Tailwind CSS add custom css stylesheet

Tags: tailwind-css

It is working when I follow the documentation on adding custom css here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn.
My working example: https://codepen.io/monkeycrane2010/pen/PodvGYd

CODE

```
<style type="text/tailwindcss">
    @layer components {
      .card {
        @apply bg-slate-200 border-4;
      }
    }
</style>

<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-3">

   <h1 class="p-2 bg-slate-200">
      Hello world!
    </h1>
</div>
 


<div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
   <div class="card border-t-purple-500"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591886891704-8f84fe0c42f0?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2ODAxNzg4OTI&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85" alt="apple from Unsplash" width="60" height="60">01 <br/> <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Open Link</a></div>
   <div class="card border-t-orange-500"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1652441547536-f6edb2fc5206?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2ODAxNzg5NDc&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85" alt="rubber duckie from Unsplash" width="60" height="60">02</div>
   <div class="card border-b-green-500">03</div>
   <div class="card">04</div>
   <div class="card">05</div>
   <div class="card">06</div> 
   <!-- ... -->
   <div>09</div>
 </div>
```

However, I don't understand how to move this code to an external css file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add it to the css file where you have declared `@layer base`,`@layer components`

Comment: using the cdn you won't be able to use a separated stylesheet you need to install tailwind as a npm package into your project or use the cli to process your input stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create the first installation setup which is the Tailwind CLI command. You can refer to this site for setup steps:- https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation then select the first option:- Tailwind CLI

Here are guidance setup steps to generate your code.

first step:
1)npm install -D tailwindcss
2)npx tailwindcss init

- it generates node-module and tailwind.config.js file

2. But In tailwind.config.js file you need to add source content(path Directory):
   which will be replaced by module.exports content: ["*","./index.html"],
3. You need to create a folder which is src inside this folder make a new file that is input.css

Directory like:

```
src
  input.css
```

4. In Input.css file you need to add
   @tailwind base;
   @tailwind components;
   @tailwind utilities;

/ your code /

```
@layer components {
  .card {
    @apply bg-slate-200 border-4;
  }
}
```

5. Run the following command to scan your files for classes. The first time when you start coding at that time you enter this command otherwise there are no reflected CSS changes when you add it.
   npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
6. Open the index.html file in your browser to run the preview

Answer (score 0):

```
 Install tailwindcss via npm, and create your tailwind.config.js file.  
 

    npm install -D tailwindcss
        npx tailwindcss init



Add the paths to all of your template files in your tailwind.config.js file.

    module.exports = {
      content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }
    Add the @tailwind directives for each of Tailwind’s layers to your main CSS file.
     @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
Run the CLI tool to scan your template files for classes and build your CSS.

    npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
Add your compiled CSS file to the <head> and start

        <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
        Hello world!
      </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```